# Need to compute/approximate a summation of the quotients of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

In my research I need to calculate the expected value of a particular distribution. The summation involved is relatively nasty; it's not something I've ever seen before. Assume $m > t$. 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^t k\frac{\binom{t}{k}}{\binom{m}{k}}
$$
It can be simplified to this:
$$
\frac{t!}{m!} \sum_{k=1}^t k\frac{(m-k)!}{(t-k)!}
$$

but that's really as far as I've gotten on my own aside from cancelling terms from the numerators and re-indexing. Anybody have an idea of how to compute this or put a good upper bound on it? Thanks very much.

EDIT: Found an identity in *Concrete Mathematics* for the quotient of binomial coefficients of this type. Now I have it down to
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}} \sum_{k=1}^{t}k\binom{m-k}{t-k}
$$
which seems much more manageable.

Comment: Doesn't look like an expectation *exactly*. Maybe a description of the original random variable would help.

Comment: Perhaps we can rewrite the expectation recursively or use linearity of expectation. As @AndréNicolas said, original random variable can help us.

Comment: (t-k)! should be in the denominator and  (m-k)! in the numerator.

Comment: Ahh, you are absolutely right. Sorry about that.

Comment: The RV is the number of iterations of a loop in a randomized algorithm involving pseudorandom permutations with particular properties.

Comment: @pg1989: The simplicity of the result suggests that you can probably get it more elegantly from the original problem. This is often the case with randomized permutations. You could post the original problem as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}} \sum_{k=1}^{t}k\binom{m-k}{t-k}
&=\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}} \sum_{k=0}^{t}(t-k)\binom{m-t+k}{k}\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}}\left(t\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{m-t+k}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{t}k\binom{m-t+k}{k}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}}\left(t\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{m-t+k}{k}-(m-t+1)\sum_{k=1}^{t}\binom{m-t+k}{k-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}}\left(t\binom{m+1}t-(m-t+1)\binom{m+1}{t-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{m}{t}}\left((m-t+2)\binom{m+1}{t-1}-(m-t+1)\binom{m+1}{t-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{\binom{m+1}{t-1}}{\binom mt}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)t}{(m-t+1)(m-t+2)}\;.
\end{align}

I suspect there's a more elegant way to get that result.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I don't quite understand the second step, where you pull the (t-k) out - can you explain that?

Comment: I think you mean the first step? It doesn't pull $t-k$ out; it replaces $k$ by $t-k$ (after adding the zero term for $k=0$).